# Автоподгрузка стран, городов на разных языках

Tags: геолокация, ajax, javascript

Добрый день.
У кого-то есть идеи каким образом некоторые сервисы, например Badoo добились такого еффекта?

Есть поле, когда начинаешь вводить в него символы, оно подгружает список стран (или городов, не суть) и показывает их в соседнем div'e. Так ладно если бы просто список стран грузился, а у них это выводит страну на английском и рядом на твоем языке (видимо по локали смотрят). К тому же оно отлично ищет и если вписать страну русскими буквами, и если английскими. И в обоих случаях рядом пишется название страны на другом языке. Какой сервис предоставляет такую услугу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервис тут не особо нужен, точнее от сервиса/ресурса вам нужна база. В вашем случае, база на двух языках. А дальше это легко реализуется с помощью того же [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (jQuery UI). Поиск происходит сразу по двум полям таблицы: с русским названием и английским.

P.S. Кстати, [вот бесплатная база](http://www.mirgorod.ru/baza-stran-i-gorodov/) на английском и русском языках, которая вам может пригодится.

Comment: так это в моем случае оно на русском добавляло)
а если мне нужно глобальный вариант?  
или это просто у них база такая большая что там все страны на всех языках уместились?)

Comment: Что такое "оно"? Куда и что это "оно" добавляло на русском? Какая база "у них" - я не знаю, т.к. с "ними" я не знаком. Но не смотря на то, что есть загадочные "оно" и "они", а количество языков зависит от вашего решения. На скольких языках найдете базу, на стольких и будет возможность поиска.